# Group Policy to disable Thumbs.db caching Server 2012 and Windows 7 clients

Tags: cache, group-policy

We are trying to push out GPO to Windows 7 clients to disable Thumbs.db caching. The setting *Turn off the caching of thumbnails in hidden thumbs.db files* is found here: User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > then either Windows Explorer (Windows 7) or File Explorer (Windows 8).

Since I am working on Server 2012 I change the setting under File Explorer. This does not change the setting under Windows Explorer on the Win7 clients when I browse to it in local gpedit. When I do RSOP it says it's applying successfully, but I'm not sure. Does the policy change some registry setting but it's just not reflected in the local gpedit.msc? How can I test whether this setting is working?

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: This is not an InfoSec question, but a Windows Administration question. Voting to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does change a registry setting:

```
Key: HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer  
Value: DisableThumbsDBOnNetworkFolders
```

You can download the settings spreadsheet here:

Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250